# If list of lists values are present in Pandas dataframe column replace them with values from another Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists with word tockens of the following type:

```
[['java_developer'],
['ETL', 'database_administrator'],
...
['web-developer', 'c#', 'ms_sql']]
```

Also I have a key-value pandas dataframe, where the first column key and the second one is value. E.g.:

```
     Key                      Value
0    java_developer           java
1    web-developer            web
2    database_administrator   database
3    ETL                      ETL
4    ms_sql                   database
... ... ...
100  c#                       c#
```

I want to receive a list of lists of the folowing type:

```
[['java'],
['ETL', 'database'],
...
['web', 'c#', 'database']]
```

How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get` for add some value for missing values from `DataFrame` like `None`:

```
#added val to last sublist for better sample
L = [['java_developer'],
['ETL', 'database_administrator'],
['web-developer', 'c#', 'ms_sql', 'val']]

#create dictionary from DataFrame
d = df.set_index('Key')['Value'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'java_developer': 'java', 'web-developer': 'web', 
 'database_administrator': 'database', 'ETL': 'ETL', 
 'ms_sql': 'database', 'c#': 'c#'}

#in nested list comprehension repalce by dict
L1 = [[d.get(y, None) for y in x] for x in L]
print (L1)
[['java'], ['ETL', 'database'], ['web', 'c#', 'database', None]]
```

Or remove not matched values add filtering:

```
L1 = [[d.get(y) for y in x if y in d] for x in L]
print (L1)
[['java'], ['ETL', 'database'], ['web', 'c#', 'database']]
```

And if need same values for not exist in dictionary:

```
L1 = [[d.get(y, y) for y in x] for x in L]
print (L1)
[['java'], ['ETL', 'database'], ['web', 'c#', 'database', 'val']]
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! I have one problem, if list of lists value is not presented in pandas dataframe, then instead it appears `None`. I want that if the value is not represented in the dataframe, then it remains the same.
Sorry, if I initially incorrectly posed the question.

Comment: @lemon - Cech last edit, need `L1 = [[d.get(y, y) for y in x] for x in L]` - change `d.get(y, None)` to `d.get(y, y)`